# Setting variables inside if / else-if statment blocks

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

I have written the code below and I am trying to work out if there is a more efficient way of doing it: i.e. less lines of code and quicker etc.

I am also wondering whether it is OK to declare variables inside of an `if` ... `else if` statement.

```
function test() {
    var x = 3;
    if (x > 5) {
        var msg = "m", state = "d";
    } else if (x < 5) {
        var msg = "a", state = "d";
    } else {
        var msg = "e", state = "n";
    }
    $('#id1').removeClass().addClass(state);
    $('#id2').html("Some text " + msg + " and more text.");
    $('#id3').attr('title', "Different text " + msg + " still different text.");
}
```

As background, the following code is the original code I had before refactoring/rewriting:

> ```
> function test() {
>   var x = 3;
>   if (x > 5) {
>         $('#id1').removeClass().addClass('d');
>         $('#id2').html("Some text message and more text.");
>         $('#id3').attr('title', "Different text message still different text.");
>   } else if (x < 5) {
>         $('#id1').removeClass().addClass('d');
>         $('#id2').html("Some text message2 and more text.");
>         $('#id3').attr('title', "Different text message2 still different text.");
>   } else {
>         $('#id1').removeClass().addClass('n');
>         $('#id2').html("Some text message3 and more text.");
>         $('#id3').attr('title', "Different text message3 still different text.");
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: Just had a 'collaboration' with Jamal. There is a lot of history on this question, and you're right, the code has not significantly changed, and your edits added more context. To be clear though, if this question was new, it would be closed as 'example code', and 'not real'. I'll restore the question with a few small modifications.

Comment: Thanks @rolfl. Just for the record, the code was 'real' code I used in a project. I'd simply reduced it down to the most relevant code for clarity and the benefit of those answering the question, so that it would be easy to read and didn't go on for lines and lines.

Comment: You're welcome, but, to be clear, your code, as it stands, can be reduced further because `x` is always `3` ... because the code makes no sense.... it's example code ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what the purpose of declaring your variable within your `if` statement is supposed to be here. For readability, I would declare those variables at the beginning of your function, like so:

```
function test() {
    var x = 3, 
        msg, 
        state;
    if (x > 5) {
        msg = "m", state = "d";
    } else if (x < 5) {
        msg = "a", state = "d";
    } else {
        msg = "e", state = "n";
    }
    $('#id1').removeClass().addClass(state);
    $('#id2').html("Some text " + msg + " and more text.");
    $('#id3').attr('title', "Different text " + msg + " still different text.");
}
```

That being said, I don't know a reason why you couldn't do so; it most depends on readability and the best practices you are following.

Comment: The idea behind it was simple. I wanted the variable to be different based on the different scenarios. So I thought I should just re/define the variable in each scenario.

Comment: But... How you declare that variable is not important. You'll see that the variable is declared anyways.

Comment: You don't want to be defining your `msg` variable inside the `if` scope because strictly speaking it shouldn't be accessible outside the `if`. Unfortunaely javascript allows us to write code like this, but its not a good idea.

Comment: @James - Yes, unfortunately JS is more forgiving than that. :)

Comment: @james and @jared I understand what you are saying. But in this version, when the values are changed in the if else if statement, should they not then both have semicolons after them instead of being seperated by a comma.

Comment: @tw16 - If you're declaring your variables in a single statement, you need to use a comma; a semicolon delimits a statement (meaning end-of-statement).

Comment: @jared - But you aren't declaring the variables any more in the if else if statement. You declared them outside of it. So now aren't you simply changing their value inside the if else if. Should that not be done as two separate lines of code i.e. separated by a semicolon?

Comment: @tw16 - Think about this for a second. If your question is whether or not your value should be set within or before an `if` statement, I think you have just answered your own question - it should be declare your variable and then set it accordingly. While the alternative is certainly possible, the best practice is to declare the (known) variables and then set them before working on them later in your script.

Comment: Ok so as I said earlier. I understand declaring it before the if statement. But then as you can see my function relies on changing the value of the variables depending on different scenarios. The first thing I was asking about your current code is when setting(not declaring) the values in the if statement should they not be seperate lines of code i.e. ended with a semicolon. And then the second thing is - In my main question I did also ask is there a more efficient way to do what I am trying to achieve i.e. another way to achieve this if what I have done is a bad idea.

Comment: @tw16 - I don't see any benefits to caching a specific or series of specific elements in your code, since you only access them once. Once you have your `if` statement setup, with your variable declarations setup according, what happens after according to your included code should be singular and non-optimizable. If it's otherwise, please post some more specific code.

Comment: All I was trying to do was make some code I already had written shorter/better/more efficient etc. If you look at my question now you can now see the original code I had before I rewrote it.

Comment: @tw16 - I think you can make this code into a function, which is what you seem to be asking. It's never perfect to every situation, so I suggest going with your gut here.

Comment: This is a one off case. I don't intend to use this code in other situations. I am just always looking to learn and improve. So I thought I would see if I could shorten (refactor) my code. So which code is better then? My original code or my 'improved' code?

Comment: I would say the *improved* code, but it's not a great improvement unless it's called many times.

Comment: If x=3, how shall it be gt 5 or not less than 5?

Comment: @jared I understand it might not be a huge improvement in the circumstances, but as I said, I am always looking to learn and improve. Which means next time a project comes along I will already have a better idea of where to start.

And you cannot see a better way of coding it other than my two versions?

Comment: @tw16 - Best practices usually mean you're handling the scenarios that happen to nearly every situation. I can't say that I have covered all of those scenarios, but I would say that until you need better performance, you will probably be ok. Keep in mind that using `count()` in a for loop is considered hazardous...

Answer (score 0):

admittedly readability usually takes a second seat to speed for me (I know a lot of you won't like that), but for me I would probably use some inline logic for smaller, faster code:

```
function test(){
    var x=3;
    $('#id1').removeClass().addClass((x==5?'n':'d'));
    $('#id2').html("Some text " + (x<5?'a':(x>5?'m':'e')) + " and more text.");
    $('#id3').attr('title', "Different text " + (x<5?'a':(x>5?'m':'e')) + " still different text.");
}
```

Comment: there is certainly a lot less of your code than in the other examples. But I think your code is not easily readable or flexible. I loathe encountering code like this. It's just my preference.

Comment: Like I said, I know a lot of you wouldn't like this, but I develop social networks almost exclusively and in my experience speed trumps readability as long as you're experienced enough to understand the code you write